# Transfer Google Play Games account

Tags: android, google-play-games

Is there any way to transfer the account that is used for tracking achievements, xp and stuff in "Google Play Games" app?

You can set a custom username for your account, so I think it might be separate from the original google account / google play account. This account is used for selling, switching emails, etc (to understand what I mean by transfer).

If I'm right, how can I separate or transfer the data / account?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to transfer certain data from one account to another. The data which can be transferred can be seen at [google take-out](https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout)

Comment: Now I can see there only Google Books, but this may be region related. Do you see there something related to Google Play? Also, it talks only about downloading data, what about recovering them?

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr Some more information about that can be found at [lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5934343/how-can-i-migrate-my-google-data-from-one-account-to-another) I will include this in my answer once I find some time